# Mongodb document limit without split document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

i want to ask about mongodb document design

I have document with structure like this

```
{
_id:123,
data:[
   [
      { name: "andy" }, ....
   ],
   [
      { price : 1000 }, ....
   ],
   .....
]}
```

i put 1 transaction into 1 document, so easy to manage data. But i have an issue when there are many data inside array, when it exceed 16mb..

I dont want to change or split the data into many document, because my application already depends on its index in data array, if i do, its painfull in application side..

Since i'm using aggregation (pagination , project), there are no performance issue when it comes to data retrieving.

I know split data into new document can solve this problem, i just only add a field reference into new document.

But if i dont want to split the document, is it posibble?

Comment: This might not be compilable syntax but try something along those lines:

`collection.find({_id:"123"}, {"data.0.0.name"}).limit(1)`

This should return only name from array at index 0 of array at index 0. If you want to return the same index from all arrays you got there, you have to use projection multiple times. [mongo docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/)

Comment: Thanks for answer @Tomasz, sorry if my question not clear, my bad english sorry.

Comment: My question is, how if document exceed more than 16 mb? i want to put all transaction into 1 document, my application always push data or edit in only that 1 document. My application running well when i do push and when document exceed more than 16mb, bum! Array cannot be push anymore because that limitation

Comment: Oh, ok, you HAVE TO split this one big document into small once, or use BLOB (highly not recommended performace vise).

Comment: Ok, ok i understand now, thanks for answer tomasz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mongodb, A document size can not be exceed 16 mb. So you can simply split the document into parts. and when you are going to access that from the back end, you can unite using [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) pipeline. 
You may use "allowDiskUse" feature for this.

Comment: Can you give me an example for this? How to split document into parts? Do you mean gridfs? Or anything else?

Comment: I mean u can save data separately without saving in one document.

Comment: If so, i should change my backend application logic to separate it into multiple document ya. Thanks for answer Lakmal!